# Python - How do I find a link on webpage that has no class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a beginner python programmer and I am trying to make a webcrawler as practice.
Currently I am facing a problem that I cannot find the right solution for. The problem is that I am trying to get a link location/address from a page that has no class, so I have no idea how to filter that specific link.
It is probably better to show you.
[The page I am trying to get the link from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1tOw.png)
As you can see, I am trying to get what is inside of the href attribute of the "Historical prices" link. Here is my python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_historicalprices_link(url):
    source = requests.get(url)
    text = source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    link = soup.find_all('li', 'fjfe-nav-sub')
    href = str(link.get('href'))
    find_spreadsheet(href)

def find_spreadsheet(url):
    source = requests.get(url)
    text = source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    link = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'nowrap'})
    href = str(link.get('href'))
    download_spreadsheet(href)

def download_spreadsheet(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    text = response.text
    lines = text.split("\\n")
    filename = r'google.csv'
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line + "\n")
    file.close()

find_historicalprices_link('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL&ei=3lowWYGRJNSvsgGPgaywDw')
```

In the function "find_spreadsheet(url)", I could easily filter the link by looking for the class called "nowrap". Unfortunately, the Historical prices link does not have such a class and right now my script just gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

How do I make sure that my crawler only takes the href from the "Historical prices"?
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I found the way to do it. By only looking for the link with a specific text attached to it, I could find the href I needed.
Solution:
soup.find('a', string="Historical prices")

Comment: Did you read your error?  This line here is causing you problems: link = soup.find_all('li', 'fjfe-nav-sub')
    href = str(link.get('href'))  Link is a list, not an element

Comment: @jarcobi889 Okay, so what do I need to do to fix this? I already changed find_all() to find() and now it just returns "None"

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code sniplet helps you? I think you can solve your problem with the following code as I hope:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a href='http://www.google.com'>Something else</a>
          <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Historical prices</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

urls = soup.find_all("a")

print(urls)

print([a["href"] for a in urls if a.text == "Historical prices"])
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it didnt. But i found the way to do it. The way i did it is by only looking for the link with that specific text. soup.find('a', string="Historical prices"). I just found out how to use this

Comment: Thx, this helps me, too. I didn't knew that possibility!